# Change size of Navigation Bar in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uikit, navigationbar, swiftui-navigationview

Hello SO community

I'm trying to recreate NavigationBar from Contact tab Apple's Phone in my SwiftUI app.
[image]

I played around with `.toolbar` and modifications but really can't recreate it. I wanna replace TextField to SegmentPicker with saving all behavior of `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`. But don't know is it possible to use SwiftUI only to get it or need to dive into UIKit. I'm not the expert of UIKit and I will be glad for any help. I want use this NavBar in a exact screen in the app and if possible do not change my preferences of NavBar on other part of app. My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavBar: View {

@State var pickerOptions: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                SegmentPicker
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Text("Groups")
            }
        }
    }
}

private var SegmentPicker: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Contacts").font(.body.weight(.semibold))
        Picker("Options", selection: $pickerOptions) {
            Text("Cons").tag(0)
            Text("Prons").tag(1)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .frame(width: 200)
    }
}
}
```